# separate tables or same table with 1 extra field?

Tags: database-design

I have a use case where I am dealing with 2 types of file transfers, upload/download. And I would like to store a history or a log of actions performed when a user downloads or uploads a file. So both have exactly same properties (action date, filename/fileid, user who did the action, etc) so let's say these info I need to store are field1, field2,  and field3.

Is it better to have a schema like:

`field1, field2,field3, type`

and keep all information in 1 table, or just have 2 different tables:

`table for type 1:field1, field2,field3`

`table for type 2:field1, field2,field3`

There is no use case where we need to show all history data (upload/download) in a list in UI side of the application. They are always shown separately to the user, depending on what page he is navigating.

Is there a real (technical) reason to pick one over the other like efficiency, a common best practice, etc or is it just a matter of taste/opinion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'd have 2 tables.  This allows you to easily evolve them separately if required.

Additionally, you then don't have to `select ... where type=?` which would not be efficient on a column with only 2 values.

Comment: "*you then don't have to `select ... where type=?` which would not be efficient on a column with only 2 values*" - Note this is not really any different in efficiency than selecting everything from one of the two Tables either.

Comment: I would go for 2 tables as well.  In my experience, things evolve and later it is so much more work to split them.

Comment: @J.D. Yeah it does make a difference at large volumes.  If you have X rows in the same table the DB will have to trawl through X rows for either upload or download regardless of what you want unless there are other criteria which, as written, there are not.

Comment: @LoztInSpace You're assuming you know the cardinality of his table though. If there are far more downloads than uploads, for example, the database engine will know to seek to just the uploads when querying for that type, or scan for the downloads when querying for that type (both appropriately efficient operations for each use case). Additionally, I expect him to index and query on more than just type, but also probably by date and / or user, which will be the same use cases and performance regardless if he uses a single table or two tables.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to pick one over the other is really going to come down to very granular things in your use cases, there's no general answer. Things like saying "*history or a log of actions*" makes me think of a transaction history table which is usually designed to be a single Table with a `Type` field.

But you go on to say "*There is no use case where we need to show all history data (upload/download) in a list in UI side of the application. They are always shown separately to the user*", which means you could separate them into two different Tables, if you chose to.

But if you think you'd ever want the ability to easily see the linear history of all actions (e.g. `User1` uploaded `FileA` then downloaded `FileA` three times), even for debugging or reporting purposes, storing all the data in a single Table makes this a simpler task, and technically more efficient.

Generally speaking, there's likely not to be much difference performance-wise either way. If you know the two objects are going to be structured consistently for the foreseeable future, then it doesn't really matter which direction you go either. And should you need to introduce a change, even if it's specific to only one of the two `Types`, it may not be a big deal to add a nullable field, or have an `...Extension` Table to represent the non-common fields.

Another thing to consider is does your application use two different object types or a single object type for `Uploads` vs `Downloads`?...the answer to *why* is the application architected in such a way may help answer how you want to architect your database.